# bash shell script concatenate string with period char

Tags: string, bash, shell, integer, echo

I am trying to create following string

```
Beta-3.8.0
```

but shell script always omits the `.` period char no matter what I do.

```
echo "$readVersion"

if [ -z $readVersion ]
then
    echo "readVersion is empty"
    exit 1
fi;

IFS=.
set $readVersion
newVersion=$(echo "$2 + 1" | bc)
newBranch="Beta-$1.$newVersion.$3"
echo $newBranch
```

prints:
**3.8.0

Beta-3 9 0**

I have also tried

```
newBranch='Beta-'$1'.'$newVersion'.'$3
or
newBranch="Beta-{$1}.{$newVersion}.{$3}"
```

although this seems printing the right value `echo "$1.$newVersion.$3"` why not variable doesnt work ?

I need the variable to use later on in the script...

Comment: Double quote your variables.

Comment: You set "IFS=." so arguments (to echo) get split at dots.  Reset IFS and the `echo` will be fine.  Enclose your argument in double quotes and you will be fine.  The variable contains the dots; it's just that you've modified IFS (for a purpose) and not restored it when that purpose is over — that is what's giving you grief.

Comment: Why are you using `set`? Just use `"$readVersion"` where you are currently using `$1`.

Comment: For more gory/scary details about the consequences of failing to quote variables, please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save and restore the `IFS` once you are done.

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=.
set $readVersion
newVersion=$(echo "$2 + 1" | bc)
IFS=$oldIFS
newBranch="Beta-$1.$newVersion.$3"
echo "$newBranch"
```

Or you can quote when printing:

```
echo "$newBranch"
```

The former is a better idea IMO since it conveys your intention and would make the rest of the code use the "correct" IFS. The latter just circumvents the problem.